Oracle Apex page process calling stored procedure not working
I have created a master detail page. On a master page, I created a Page Process which calls a stored procedure on button click and save a master record in a table, which works fine as expected. On a detail page I created similar Page Process which calls a stored procedure on button click and expected to save the detail records in a table but when the button is clicked it gives message Rows Updated Successfully but actually no rows got inserted into the table. Could not figure out why the record is not inserted in the table. The procedure works fine when call directly from database.
Here is my Page Process - Insert Option



Here is the page I am adding the detail record.

when I clicked the Create button the record did not inserted into table.

I am expecting the record get inserted into the detail table.

Currently, processes are executed in this order:

close dialog
insert options

which means that dialog gets closed and ... nothing else happens. So, switch their positions to

insert options
close dialog


It worked. Thank You

You're welcome.
